# Как создать массив строк из случайной длины и случайных значений

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, циклы

Есть функция, которая выводит рандомную длину заданного массива. Как сделать так, чтобы выводился массив случайной длинны из случайных значений?
Значения, которые рандомно выводятся не должны повторяться.

```
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  const minNumber = Math.ceil(min);
  const maxNumber = Math.floor(max);
  if ( maxNumber < minNumber){
    throw new RangeError('Значение максильного числа не должно быть меньше значения минимального числа');
  } else if (maxNumber === minNumber) {
    throw new RangeError('Максимальное значение числа не должно быть равно минимальному значению числа. Результат + min');
  } else {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber - minNumber + 1)) + minNumber;
  }
}

const features = ['wifi', 'dishwasher', 'parking', 'washer', 'elevator', 'conditioner'];

function getArray(features) {
  const maxLength = features.length;
  const lengthOfArray = getRandomNumber(1, maxLength);
  const array = [];
  
  for(var i = 0;i < lengthOfArray;i++) {
    const indexOfEl = getRandomNumber(0, 5);
    const el = features[indexOfEl];
    
    if (!array.includes(el)) {
      array.push(el);
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const features = ['wifi', 'dishwasher', 'parking', 'washer', 'elevator', 'conditioner'];

function getArray(features) {
  const maxLength = features.length;
  const lengthOfArray = getRandomNumber(1, maxLength);
  const array = [];

  while (array.length < lengthOfArray) {
    const indexOfEl = getRandomNumber(0, maxLength - 1);
    const el = features[indexOfEl];

    if (!array.includes(el)) {
      array.push(el);
    }
  }
  return array;

  function getRandomNumber(from, to) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1)) + from;
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getArray(features)));
```

Comment: Функция же не выводит не повторяющиеся значения

Comment: @Мила Да? А что он делает?

Comment: @Мила Так лучше?

Comment: Да, спасибо!) 
Я поняла)

Comment: @Мила Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

```
const createRandomUniqArray = (array) =>{
  const arr = Array.from(array);
  const arrayNew = new Array(getRndInteger(1, arr.length));
  for (let id=0; id<arrayNew.length; id++ ){
    arrayNew[id]=arr.splice(getRndInteger(0, arr.length-1), 1).join();
  }
  return arrayNew;
};

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  if (min<0||max<=min){
    throw new Error('Диапазон неверен');
  }
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
const features = ['wifi', 'dishwasher', 'parking', 'washer', 'elevator', 'conditioner'];

const getRandomPositiveInteger = (a, b) => {
  const lower = Math.ceil(Math.min(Math.abs(a), Math.abs(b)));
  const upper = Math.floor(Math.max(Math.abs(a), Math.abs(b)));
  const result = Math.random() * (upper - lower + 1) + lower;
  return Math.floor(result);
};

const getNewArray = () => {
  const newArray = [];
  const newArrayLength = getRandomPositiveInteger(1, features.length);

  for (let i = 1; i <= newArrayLength; i++) {
  const options = features.shift();
  newArray.push(options);
}  

  return newArray;
}

getNewArray();
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]